# How to find data within embedded documents array using id mongodb?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am using mongodb with nodejs to find data in embedded document. strange fact is query works in database but not in actual nodejs code.

here is my data object:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5c65866488a1c53464e46dc7"),
"cat_lang" : [
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5c65866488a1c53464e46dc8"),
        "en" : "temp",
        "it" : "temp"
    }
],
"providers" : [
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5c65866488a1c53464e46dc9"),
        "provider_name" : "temp0",
        "url" : "http://uber.com",

    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5c65866488a1c53464e46dca"),
        "provider_name" : "temp1",
        "url" : "http://uber2.com",
    }
]}
```

I have tried these queries in the mongodb shell works perfectly fine.

```
db.sideservices.findOne({"_id" : ObjectId("5c65866488a1c53464e46dc7")},{providers: {$elemMatch: {"_id" : ObjectId("5c65866488a1c53464e46dca")}}})
```

AND

```
db.sideservices.find({"providers._id":ObjectId("5c65866488a1c53464e46dca")},{'providers.$':1})
```

But when using the same functions in nodejs, it returns the whole object instead document with the given id.

```
this.db.collection('sideservices').find({'providers':{'$elemMatch':{'_id':ObjectId('5c65866488a1c53464e46dca')}}}).toArray((err,res) => {...})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this way

```
this.collection("sideservices").find({
  "providers": { "$elemMatch": { "_id": ObjectId("5c65866488a1c53464e46dca") } }
})
.project({
  "providers": { "$elemMatch": { "_id": ObjectId("5c65866488a1c53464e46dca") } }
})
.toArray((err,res) => {...})
```

Comment: Hi @Anthony Winzlet if you see my question I have already tried this approach for some reason it doesn't fetch the exact document but fetches whole object. What I mean is  
from "_id" : ObjectId("5c65866488a1c53464e46dc7"), to end. What is required to get a single document only of  this Id --> "_id" : ObjectId("5c65866488a1c53464e46dca") thanks

Comment: This is something different. Try the above answer with you nodejs code. Then I will let you know the issue

Comment: Hi thanks man you are a life saver !! I have spent whole day on it but that worked like charmed